# Найти длину пути между точками, проходящего вне окружности

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, геометрия

У меня возникли проблемы с решением задачи по программированию на геому. Надо посчитать длину такого кратчайшего пути между точками, чтобы он не проходил внутри окружности. (Точки и путь могут лежать на самой окружности). Можете, пожалуйста сказать как решать в теории или запрогать.(если код, то желательно на с++/python)

Формат ввода:
Во входном файле записаны сначала координаты точек: x1, y1, x2, y2, а затем — координаты центра и радиуса окружности: Ox, Oy, r. Все координаты — целые числа из диапазона от -32000 до 32000. Радиус окружности — натуральное число, не превышающее 32000.

Формат вывода:
Выведите в выходной файл одно число — длину самого короткого безопасного пути с точностью не менее 6 знаков после запятой.

Comment: Какие идеи уже сами рассмотрели?

Comment: Касательные к окружности, а между точками касания - по окружности?

Comment: Да, наверно. Но находить длину дуги и координаты точек касания?

Comment: Ну вариант я вижу такой: ищем, есть ли пересечение линии и окружности https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html Если нет пересечения, то линия — кратчайший путь, если нет, то тут два варианта: а) точки удалены достаточно от окружности, чтобы на окружности найти точку и через нее провести две линии, либо если точки близко к окружности, то строим касательные к окружности, а между точками касания считаем длину дуги.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Есть простая аналогия. Представьте натянутую нить. Вы ее приближаете к какому-то препятствию круглой формы. Так вот при соприкосновении с препятствием у Вас будет траектория наименьшей длины. Единственное, что нужно проверить подход с двух сторон.

Comment: @AndyPavlov "а: а) точки удалены достаточно от окружности, чтобы на окружности найти точку и через нее провести две линии," - как вы себе это представляете? Это возможно в **единственном** случае - когда прямая между точками касается окружности.